# how solve ArrayIndexOfBoundsException

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to develop a ListView with points and date from a game. But i want to put a picture next to each point. these images i have in an array, but when i execute the app it goes slow, the app stops and finish and it shows  ArrayIndexOfBoundsException length= 54 index = 54.
And that's my code:

```
public class TodoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Vector<String> todoList;
Context contexto;
TypedArray trofeos;

public TodoAdapter(Context context, Vector<String> todoList) {

    this.todoList = todoList;
    contexto = context;
    trofeos=contexto.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.imagenes);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return todoList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return todoList.elementAt(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    HolderA holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(contexto);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, null);
        holder = new HolderA();
        holder.imagen=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv);
        holder.puntos = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        holder.fecha = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (HolderA) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.imagen.setImageDrawable(trofeos.getDrawable(position));
    holder.puntos.setText(getItem(position).toString().substring(0,
            getItem(position).toString().length() - 19));
    holder.fecha.setText(getItem(position).toString().substring(
            getItem(position).toString().length() - 19,
            getItem(position).toString().length()));
    return convertView;
}

static class HolderA {
    ImageView imagen;
    TextView puntos;
    TextView fecha;
}
```

eclipse shows the error in holder.imagen.setImageDrawable(trofeos.getDrawable(position));
any idea?? pleaseeeee

```
05-16 22:42:32.710: E/InputEventReceiver(2784): Exception dispatching input event.
05-16 22:42:32.790: E/AndroidRuntime(2784): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 22:42:32.790: E/AndroidRuntime(2784): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=54; index=54
```

Comment: Can you add logging to get the size of `todoList` and the size of `trofeos`?  It looks like  you may have more items in `todoList` than you have in `trofeos`.

Comment: todoList is an list with 10 items and trofeos is the same, but i don't know, any idea for to put pictures nexto to points?

Comment: Hmm, where did the length of 54 come from? Something somewhere has a length of 54!  Can you show more of your stacktrace?

Comment: I have no idea, i think..

Comment: the other class and the array in http://pastebin.com/L361XTJf

Comment: Can you add your full stacktrace to the question?  It should tell you the exact line that causes the problem.  The issue is definitely not in the code you currently have in your question.

Comment: oh i found the error, in the code of array i had nine items instead of 10 item. i'm sorry. Thanks for your help Bro!!

Comment: Note that the answer you accepted has incorrect information in it, and it also has nothing to do with how you solved your issue. You should ask him to revise the answer if you are going to accept it, since it might be confusing to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
holder.fecha.setText(getItem(position).toString().substring(
            getItem(position).toString().length() - 19,
            getItem(position).toString().length()));
```

This is error place, as documentation says :

> substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) Returns a new string that is a
>   substring of this string.

As you can see, you need to use  `getItem(position).toString().length() - 1` instead of  `getItem(position).toString().length()`, because index starts with 0, but count starts with 1

Comment: I used to have the images placed in the ListView code worked perfectly, but the images not working. I tried your code and is not working.

Comment: Note that with `substring()`, beginIndex is inclusive, and endIntex is exclusive, so the problem is not in that code.

Comment: oh i found the error, in the code of array i had nine items instead of 10 item. i'm sorry. Thanks for your help Bro!!

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go

```
        holder.imagen.setImageDrawable(trofeos.getDrawable(position-1));
holder.puntos.setText(getItem(position-1).toString().substring(0,
        getItem(position-1).toString().length() - 19));
    holder.fecha.setText(getItem(position-1).toString().substring(
        getItem(position-1).toString().length() - 19,
        getItem(position-1).toString().length()));
```

Comment: it not works, when the activity start, "unfortunately, project has stopped"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only have 9 items in your array in the xml.
This results in a size miss-match between `todoList` and `trofeos`, which is what causes the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, as your adapter data source has a size of 10:

```
maxRegis=bd.listaPuntos(10);
TodoAdapter adaptador= new TodoAdapter(this,maxRegis);
```

Either make the data source of the adapter have a size of 9, or add another item to youf list of drawables:

```
<array name="imagenes">
    <item name="elemento1">@drawable/oro</item>
    <item name="elemento2">@drawable/plata</item>
    <item name="elemento3">@drawable/bronce</item>
    <item name="elemento3">@drawable/bronce</item>
    <item name="elemento3">@drawable/bronce</item>
    <item name="elemento3">@drawable/bronce</item>
    <item name="elemento3">@drawable/bronce</item>
    <item name="elemento3">@drawable/bronce</item>
    <item name="elemento3">@drawable/bronce</item>
</array>
```